# Размер изображения и родительского div'a

Tags: scss, compass

Использую compass и сетку susy.

10-колоночный формат, ширина 960px. Основная часть - 7 колонок и сайдбар, соответственно, 3.

Wrapper имеет ширину в 7 колонок. Изображению в scss указываю длину тоже 7 колонок.

*HTML*

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/710x300">
</div>`
```

*SCSS*

```
#wrapper {
  @include span(7 of 10);
  img {
      width: span(7 of 7);
  }
}`
```

**Проблема:**
Высота wrapper'а становится на несколько пикселей больше чем высота изображения.

[Пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVKqNP):

```css
@import "compass";
@import "susy";

$susy: (
    columns: 10,
    container: 960px,
    gutters: 1/4,
    global-box-sizing: border-box,
    debug: (image: hide)
);

@include border-box-sizing;

main {
  @include container;
}

#wrapper {
  @include span(7 of 10);
  background-color: #000000;
  img {
      width: span(7 of 7);
    }
}

#right_menu {
  @include span(3 of 10 last);
  ul li {
    margin-bottom: gutter();
  }
}

p {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/710x300">
  </div>
  <nav id="right_menu">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>Чёрная полоска - это выпирающий wrapper</p>
</main>
```